# NoReverseMatch at /contact/ Reverse for 'contact_result' not found. 'contact_result' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I am trying to make a contact form, but I guess I'm doing it wrong.

When I access /contact and put name, email, content in each field and click a submit button, I got an error.

> NoReverseMatch at /contact/    Reverse for 'contact_result' not found.
> 'contact_result' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

**view.py**

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import ContactForm

class ContactFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'contact/contact_form.html'
    form_class = ContactForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('contact_result')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.send_email()
        return super().form_valid(form)


class ContactResultView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contact/contact_result.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['success'] = "completed"
        return context
```

**urls.py**

```
from . import views
from .views import DbDetail,ContactFormView, ContactResultView

app_name = 'db'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.DbList.as_view(), name='list'),
    path('contact/', ContactFormView.as_view(), name='contact_form'),
    path('contact/result/', ContactResultView.as_view(), name='contact_result'),  
]
```

**contact_form.html**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h1>inquily</h1>
      <p>inquily form</p>
      <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

**contact_result.html**

```
{% block content %}
{{ success }}
{% endblock %}
```

I just mentioned the above settings in this question but still if more code is required then tell me I'll update my question with that information.

Comment: Can you view `contact/result/` page directly?

Comment: @Biplove Lamichhane Please teach me how to write a code to move to contact/result/ page directly.

Sorry, I'm a complete beginner.

Comment: What I am saying is.... got to your address like: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/result/

Comment: @Biplove Lamichhane Problem was solved. Thank you very much.
If you post that comment as an answer, I'll choose as the best answer.